# clear html select option group

Tags: javascript

I know you can clear options by doing the following:

> dropDownList.options.length = 0;

Is there a way to clear option groups?  Seems like the only way is to remove nodes one at a time.

Comment: var myOptionGroup = document.getElementById('myOptionGroup');
dropDownList.removeChild(myOptionGroup);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try getting ahold of the `optgroup` element and then remove it from the DOM:

```
<body>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="npup(this);">
    <optgroup label="Foo" id="foo_group">
        <option value="foo0">foo0</option>
        <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Bar" id="bar_group">
        <option value="bar0">bar0</option>
        <option value="bar1">bar1</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="kill_foo">Remove foo</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

function npup(selectElem) {
    // get value and check it
    var value = selectElem.value, foo;
    if (value==='kill_foo') {
        // retrieve optgroup
        foo = document.getElementById('foo_group');
        // remove the group from its parent
        foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was some other way, but removeChild worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
document.getElementById("foo_group").innerHTML = '';
```