# How to dynamically insert a <optgroup> into a listbox

Tags: javascript

I can't find a good example of how to **dynamically** insert group options for options in a select box.  The one example I did find at w3CSchools seems to only select one item [example at w3cSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_optgroup_create)

This is my less than adequate code where I just insert another option without a value ahead of each group.  I would like to have the 3 group labels inserted as group options as the list of options are streamed out which will make them bold and indent the item below.

```
var list = aCallBack.docs;
//build document list select options
document.getElementById("delDoc").options.length = 0;
document.getElementById("delDoc").options[0] = new Option("Select Document To Delete", "", true, true);

var optLen = document.getElementById("delDoc").options.length;
document.getElementById("delDoc").options[optLen] = new Option("Job Scope Documents", "", true, true);
for (i = 0; i < list.scope.length; i++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = list.scope[i];
    optn.value = list.scope[i];
    document.getElementById("delDoc").options.add(optn);
}

var optLen = document.getElementById("delDoc").options.length;
document.getElementById("delDoc").options[optLen] = new Option("Field Reports", "", true, true);

for (i = 0; i < list.field.length; i++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = list.field[i];
    optn.value = list.field[i];
    document.getElementById("delDoc").options.add(optn);
}

var optLen = document.getElementById("delDoc").options.length;
document.getElementById("delDoc").options[optLen] = new Option("Final Reports", "", true, true);

for (i = 0; i < list.final.length; i++) {
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = list.final[i];
    optn.value = list.final[i];
    document.getElementById("delDoc").options.add(optn);
}

document.getElementById("delDoc").selectedIndex = 0;
```

A simple example not using jQuery would be appreciated

Comment: Does your `<select>` element have the `multiple` atrribute, as you're  setting every created option as `selected` *and* `defaultSelected`? Incidentally, if you post your starting HTML as well as the final expected output HTML it will be easier for us to help provide better answers.

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/y5jd4pbp/)?

Comment: @Teemu - Consider posting the code as an answer. All similar SO questions appear to use jQuery whereas your answer is plain JS. Good answer.

Comment: David thanks for point out that I had set every group level as selected.  That was an error on my part and should not have been.

Comment: Teemu.  Thanks for the help.  Your suggestion appears to be just what I was looking for.  Will try to implement it.  When you see it, it looks so obvious.  BTW what does the "true" represent in this line group.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));   And as Roberto said please post your response as an answer.

Comment: @Claus `true` is a parameter which tells to `cloneNode` to copy the whole node with all its children. If `false` was passed, only an empty `opt` element would be copied. The parameter is not actually needed here, since `opt` has no children. I'm just used to use it "as default". You can read more at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Teemu for the solution I was able to get the group header in the drop down list.  As a side benefit I was also able to shorten the code with an extra outer loop.  Here is the revised code.

```
    this.getFileListResponse = function(msg)
{
    aCallBack = JSON.parse(msg);
    if (aCallBack.errors.length==0)
    {
        //simplfy reference to call back results
        var list = aCallBack.docs;

        //delete any previous entries
        document.getElementById("delDoc").options.length=0;

        //build document list select options
        document.getElementById("delDoc").options[0]=new Option( "Select Document To Delete" , "", true, true);

        //double array to store reference to returned records as well as the group header
        var groups = [['scope','Job Scope Documents'],['field','Field Reports'],['final','Final Reports']];


        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var group = document.createElement('optgroup'),
                opt = document.createElement('option'),
                n;

            //retrive group label from groups array
            group.label = groups[i][1];

            //retrive document name from the call back data stored in list
            //in this case I used a single value for both the text and value of the option
            //  that could easily be expanded into separate items.
            for (n = 0; n < list[groups[i][0]].length; n++) {
                opt.value = list[groups[i][0]][n];
                opt.text  = list[groups[i][0]][n];
                group.appendChild(opt.cloneNode(true));
            }
            document.getElementById('delDoc').appendChild(group);
        }

    }else{
        aMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < aCallBack.errors.length; i++)
            aMsg += aCallBack.errors[i]+'\n';

        alert(aMsg);
    }

};
```

Here are the before and after screen shots of the original and revised code
[Using the old code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcZ8M.gif) and [Using the revised code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvnea.gif)

Just one annoying feature remains.  If the user click the button to list the documents twice, the group labels are inserted twice, even though the routine starts out with clearing out the previous content.  This problem also occurred in the w3cSchools example I posted in my original question.  So if someone has a solution to that problem that would great.  Sorry do not have enough reputations to also post this failing image.  Please check out the example in w3cSchools I posted above click the button twice to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You're clearing options only, a simple `#deldoc.innerHTML = ''` would remove optgroups too.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for how to remove option groups for list box [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581004/clear-html-select-option-group)

Since I clear the list box in two places I just created this little method and call it from each location.

```
function clearDocList()
{
var optgrp = ['scope','field','final'];
if (document.getElementById('scope'))
{
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        grp = document.getElementById(optgrp[i]);
        // remove the group from its parent
        grp.parentNode.removeChild(grp);
    }
    document.getElementById("delDoc").options[0]=new Option( "Select Document To Delete" , "", true, true);
}
```

}

One other change had to be made to the code.  Since this function requires the use of the elements id.  I had to add an id to each group like so.

```
            //retrive group label from groups array
            group.id    = groups[i][0];
            group.label = groups[i][1];
```

Notice just before I assign the group label I use the first array value to assign the group id.  This now allows me to reference that group in the list.

Comment: small error in my posting the closing curly bracket } appears below the code insert.